# Error when trying to update samba4 with available packages

Tags: centos6, samba, yum, samba4

In our production environment, I need to apply a security patch by updating with the latest samba4 packages. On a centOS 6 build.

I know there is available packages for samba4 when I do (yum info samba4)

```
[root@server ~]# yum info samba4
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftpmirror.your.org
 * epel: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * extras: ftp.osuosl.org
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
Available Packages
Name        : samba4
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 4.2.10
Release     : 12.el6_9
Size        : 428 k
Repo        : updates
Summary     : Server and Client software to interoperate with Windows machines
URL         : http://www.samba.org/
License     : GPLv3+ and LGPLv3+
Description : Samba is the standard Windows interoperability suite of programs for Linux and Unix.
```

However, when I go and do the update, it doesn't get installed.

```
[root@server ~]# yum update samba4
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftpmirror.your.org
 * epel: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * extras: ftp.osuosl.org
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
Package(s) samba4 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update
```

I know samba is installed on this box

```
[root@server ~]$ rpm -qa | grep samba
samba-winbind-3.6.23-45.el6_9.x86_64
samba-common-3.6.23-45.el6_9.x86_64
samba-client-3.6.23-45.el6_9.x86_64
samba4-libs-4.2.10-11.el6_9.x86_64
samba-winbind-clients-3.6.23-45.el6_9.x86_64
```

Any ideas to why I can't update samba4 ?

Thanks

Comment: Your output shows that `samba4` is _not_ installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `yum update samba4` because `samba4` isn't installed hence it being listed in `available packages` and the message that you are getting when you attempt to install it.

If you want `samba4` the command you need is:

```
yum install samba4
```